# Local Simulator for Aquila Aws

Tags: quantum-gate

I am new to this field, so i would like to be sure that the local simulator is actually free.
Then, I would like to know how to check the number of qubits avaiable in the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i would like to be sure that the local simulator is actually free

The Local simulator is free because it directly runs on your machine. To be extremely sure that this is the case, you can temporarily disable your machine's internet connection while running the simulator or make sure that the call to the simulator is not making a network call to AWS:

```python
import socket

from boto3 import Session
from braket.aws import AwsSession, AwsDevice
from braket.devices import LocalSimulator

classical_device = LocalSimulator("braket_ahs")

nshots = 1000

def guard(*args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception("I told you not to use the Internet!")
socket.socket = guard

# You'll need to define your own ahs_program. See https://www.quera.com/using-aquila for an example
task = classical_device.run(ahs_program, shots=nshots)
```

Notice that the exception is thrown when trying to instantiate an `AWSDevice`:

```python
import socket
from braket.aws import AwsDevice, AwsSession
from boto3 import Session

def guard(*args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception("I told you not to use the Internet!")
socket.socket = guard

boto_session = Session(region_name="us-east-1")
aws_session = AwsSession(boto_session)

aquila = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:us-east-1::device/qpu/quera/Aquila",aws_session) 
# Throws botocore.exceptions.HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: I told you not to use the Internet!
```

> I would like to know how to check the number of qubits available in the simulator.

There is no upper limit on the number of qubits for the simulator:

```python
# aquila = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:us-east-1::device/qpu/quera/Aquila",aws_session)
# Throws botocore.exceptions.HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: I told you not to use the Internet!

classical_device = LocalSimulator("braket_ahs")

print(classical_device.properties)
# prints
# service={'executionWindows': [{'executionDay': 'Everyday', 'windowStartHour': '00:00', 'windowEndHour': '23:59:59'}], 'shotsRange': [0, 9223372036854775807]} action={'braket.ir.ahs.program': {}}
```

Notice that there is not `qubitCountProperty` unlike:

```python
socket.socket = unmocked_socket

aquila = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:us-east-1::device/qpu/quera/Aquila",aws_session)
print(aquila.properties.paradigm.qubitCount)
# prints
# 256
```